# sql count statement with multiple date ranges

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two table with different appointment dates.

Table 1

```
id  start date
1   5/1/14
2   3/2/14
3   4/5/14
4   9/6/14
5   10/7/14
```

Table 2

```
id  start date
1   4/7/14
1   4/10/14
1   7/11/13
2   2/6/14
2   2/7/14
3   1/1/14
3   1/2/14
3   1/3/14
```

If i had set date ranges i can count each appointment date just fine but i need to change the date ranges.
For each id in table 1 I need to add the distinct appointment dates from table 2 BUT only
6 months prior to the start date from table 1.
Example: count all distinct appointment dates for id 1 (in table 2) with appointment dates between 12/1/13 and 5/1/14 (6 months prior). So the result is 2...4/7/14 and 4/10/14 are within and 7/1/13 is outside of 6 months.

So my issue is that the range changes for each record and i can not seem to figure out how to code this.For id 2 the date range will be 9/1/14-3/2/14 and so on.

Thanks everyone in advance!

Comment: Ive used this for the date range before when i didnt need to change the date DATEADD(MM, -6, getdate())

Comment: Based on the comment, I am assuming the database is SQL Server (and tagged the question as such).

Comment: thanks for the quick responses. i will give these options a try tomorrow when i have the dataset to work with! regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this out:

```
 SELECT id,
        (
            SELECT  COUNT(*)
            FROM    table2
            WHERE   id = table1.id
                AND table2.start_date >= DATEADD(MM,-6,table1.start_date)
        ) AS table2records
 FROM   table1
```

The DATEADD subtracts 6 months from the date in table1 and the subquery returns the count of related records.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is a type of join.

```
select t1.id, count(t2.id) as numt2dates
from table1 t1 left outer join
     table2 t2
     on t1.id = t2.id and
        t2.startdate between dateadd(month, -6, t1.startdate) and t1.startdate
group by t1.id;
```

The exact syntax for the date arithmetic depends on the database.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you this solved my issue. Although this may not help you since you are not attempting to group by date. But the answer gave me the insights to resolve the issue I was facing.

I was attempting to gather the total users a date criteria that had to be evaluated by multiple fields.

> WITH data AS (
> SELECT generate_series(
> (date '2020-01-01')::timestamp,
> NOW(),
> INTERVAL '1 week'
> ) AS date
> )
>
> SELECT d.date, (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT h.id) AS user_count
> FROM history h WHERE h.startDate < d.date AND h.endDate > d.date
> ORDER BY 1 DESC) AS total_records
> FROM data d ORDER BY d.date DESC

2022-05-16, 15
2022-05-09, 13
2022-05-02, 13
...